# If $3x^{2}-2(a-d)x+(a^{2}+2(b^{2}+c^{2})+d^{2})=2(ab+bc+cd)$, then

Tags: sequences-and-series, quadratics

If $3x^{2}-2(a-d)x+(a^{2}+2(b^{2}+c^{2})+d^{2})=2(ab+bc+cd)$, then

$A.$ a,b,c,d are in G.P.
$B.$ a,b,c,d are in H.P.
$C.$ a,b,c,d are in A.P.
$D.$ None of the above

Tried writing the expression as a sum of squares but it was of no use.

NOTE: G.P.- Geometric progression, H.P.-Harmonic Progression and A.P.-Arithmetic Progression. $x,a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{R}$

Comment: What are $"G.P.", "H.P.", "A.P."$?

Comment: $$(a-b)^2+(b-c)^2+(c-d)^2$$ and $$a-d=a-b+b-c+c-d$$

Comment: Is there any other information like nature of roots?

Comment: If we write $a-b=A,b-c=B,c-d=C$, the discriminant will be $$4(A+B+C)^2-4\cdot3(A^2+B^2+C^2)=-8\{\sum(A-B)^2\}$$

Comment: No there is no other info. I have written the question as it was.

Comment: @mathlove, G.p.- Geometric progression, H.P.-Harmonic Progression and A.P.-Arithmetic Progression.

Comment: @labbhattacharjee, what should I do after that substitution ??

Comment: @Apurv, if we assume $x$ to be real, discriminant must be $\ge0$ Compare this condition with the value I've derived in the last comment

Comment: What if we allow x to take unreal values ??

Comment: @Labbhattacharjee Your discriminant $-8\sum(A-B)^2$ seems to vanish on arithmetic progressions only. This should be an answer IMO, since it rules out geometric and harmonic progressions, and allows arithmetics.

Comment: @coffeemath,agreed:) . But, the assumption I had to introduce "x to be real", thwarted me write this is as an answer

Comment: @labbhattacharjee If the assumption $x$ real is dropped, then for *any* sequence $a,b,c,d$ there would be a (possibly complex) solution $x$ to the equation, so that the question makes little sense: No restriction on them could only mean "all of the above can occur".

Answer (score -1):

I wrote and put it in the **jpg** format.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PNNYa.jpg]

I hope it helps!

Comment: The answer is helpful but please use mathjax!